# Mark specific lines of paragraph text

Tags: html, css

Given an HTML Paragraph Element (e.g., `<p>`) with some text runs marked with a HTML Mark Element (e.g., `<mark>`) I'd like to put a vertical line in the margin/gutter (not sure what the best word is) that has the same position and height as the `<mark>`.

I have made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5811ycc5/) that illustrates the quandry. Notice that the green vertical lines are the correct height. They are just in the wrong position. Ideally, I'd like them to be all the way to the left where the border of the `p` tag is.

The markup is not set in stone and can be modified. My hope is to do this purely as CSS; that is *without* JavaScript. If it cannot be done then I know how to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: No....don't see how this can be done **without** JS.

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set to  the p element overflow:hidden, and a background all white except the left most border.

And then , the pseudo on the mark with a very high width, and z-index negative to put it behind the p (so that only shows on the border

```css
div p {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 5px, white 5px);
}

div p mark.changed-text {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

div p mark.changed-text::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -10;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: green;}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Phasellus sed volutpat leo. Suspendisse mi nisi, varius id erat vel, molestie luctus justo. Nulla aliquam vestibulum tellus a sollicitudin. Duis iaculis ut ligula eget semper.
    <mark class="changed-text">Curabitur ullamcorper risus sapien, sit amet mollis lorem finibus eget. Donec imperdiet ac massa in vehicula. Phasellus a lectus sagittis, imperdiet nibh et, vehicula lectus.</mark>
    Donec metus ligula, molestie sit amet sodales et, varius vel lorem. Donec ut ante sit amet velit hendrerit facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi tincidunt turpis sed nulla finibus
    venenatis. Proin viverra venenatis sem, sed elementum sem vestibulum nec. Nulla vitae facilisis nisi, id finibus mauris. Donec volutpat nulla neque, eu laoreet lacus imperdiet imperdiet.
    <mark class="changed-text">Etiam finibus quam urna, ut fermentum tellus scelerisque cursus.</mark> Morbi eu tellus consectetur, varius eros sit amet, interdum mi.
  </p>
</div>
```